# keras CNN model predicts fine but only one label doesn't predict

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

After I train the model to predict the label of 24 class using 2800 images for each class and take 5000 images for validation I run some tests to see the quality of prediction for the label, I designed a program to take all the images in folder test and predict the label all the classes were good except class 19 which of a 1000 images for test none where predicted as 19

Does anyone have a solution?

this is the model architecture:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2,padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,1)))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(24, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

this is the optimizer and trainer:

```
optimizer = rmsprop(learning_rate=0.0001)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer= optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='CNN_newData.hdf5',verbose=1,
                               save_best_only=True)
hist = model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=100,
                 validation_data=(x_valid,y_valid),callbacks=[checkpointer],
                 verbose=2,shuffle=True)
```

this is how the images are prepared for prediction:

```
  for img in images:

            read_img = cv2.imread('test-images/' + file + '/' + img)
            read_img = cv2.cvtColor(read_img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
            read_img = read_img.reshape( -1,32, 32, 1)
            read_img = read_img.astype('float32')/255
            maxind = model.predict_classes(read_img)
```

Answer (score 2):

- I assume your data set is well-balanced?
- Could you please upload your loss/accuracy curves?
- Have you tried other optimizers? Your `RMSprop` *learning_rate* is lower than default and net rather shallow.
- Is it possible for you to share the data? Are you at least sure, there's no contradictory knowledge there?

> read_img = cv2.imread('test-images/' + file + '/' + img)

Please don't concat paths yourself. You'll run into troubles, once you'll push this model to some linux-based cloud. Check [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

- try running `adam` with default params
- `model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))`  - it's rather large for only 24 labels after it. Try something smaller, like 240.
- *kernel_size* looks weird, shouldn't conv kernel be odd? try *kernel_size=3*
- try to add some regularization

Comment: the dataset is balanced (2800 train images, 1000 test images)
I don't have loss/accuracy curves (don't know how to plot them using Keras )
yes I tried Adam optimizer same result (as for the learning rate I decreased it cause the model was doing big steps)
as for the data I cant share them cause it does belong to a company but I add more data by using Keras augmentation 
the path is only for a personal test to see the accuracy for each label alone

Comment: per each class?

Comment: I implemented everything you said except the regularization step do you have any documentation I can understand it and i saw a video the developed mnist classification they used 1024 in the dense layer so why should I decrease it to 240 for example

Comment: If your net's capacity is too high, it'll overfit, even if entropy is low.

Check this [post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/09/19/understanding-regularization-for-image-classification-and-machine-learning/) and [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-reduce-generalization-error-in-deep-neural-networks-with-activity-regularization-in-keras/) one.

Comment: There're little hard-rules when it comes to architecture. You must fiddle with params to gain some intuition. Otherwise you'll die waiting while tuning hyper-params of your model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202626/discussion-between-hassan-mohammad-and-piotr-rarus).